# iOS Aviary SDK forced crop image

Tags: ios, aviary

How to forced crop image with crop preset automatically. Says using square crop at start of editing image with aviary. I saw here is a web feature for it, but can't find info about mobile implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is no feature to force crop an image. Just for web version.